# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict

Tags: c++, opencv, cocos2d-x, svm

I'm trying to use OpenCV SVM classifier in cocos2d-x game. Here's a simple test function:

```
void HelloWorld::testOpenCV(){
    // Load SVM classifier
    auto classifierPath = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("classifier.yml");
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::StatModel::load<cv::ml::SVM>(classifierPath);

    string filename = "test.jpg";

    auto img = new Image();
    img->initWithImageFile(filename);

    int imageSize = (int)img->getDataLen();
    int imageXW = img->getWidth();
    int imageYW = img->getHeight();
    unsigned char * srcData = img->getData();

    CCLOG("imageXW=%d, imageYW=%d", imageXW, imageYW);
    int ch = imageSize/(imageXW*imageYW);
    CCLOG("image=%dch raw data...", ch);

    cv::Mat testMat = createCvMatFromRaw(srcData, imageXW, imageYW, ch);
    testMat.convertTo(testMat, CV_32F);

    // try to predict which number has been drawn
    try{
        int predicted = svm->predict(testMat);

        CCLOG("Recognizing following number -> %d", predicted);

    }catch(cv::Exception ex){

    }
}
```

And it gives an output:

```
imageXW=28, imageYW=28
image=3ch raw data...
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1930
```

It is based on this tutorial:

https://www.simplicity.be/article/recognizing-handwritten-digits/

Especially on this method:

```
// Standard library
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// OpenCV
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

// POSIX
#include <unistd.h>

/**
 * main
 **/ 
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    //
    // Load SVM classifier 
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::StatModel::load<cv::ml::SVM>("classifier.yml");


    // read image file (grayscale)
    cv::Mat imgMat = cv::imread("test.jpg", 0);

    // convert 2d to 1d 
    cv::Mat testMat = imgMat.clone().reshape(1,1);
    testMat.convertTo(testMat, CV_32F);

    // try to predict which number has been drawn
    try{
        int predicted = svm->predict(testMat);

        std::cout << std::endl  << "Recognizing following number -> " << predicted << std::endl << std::endl;

        std::string notifyCmd = "notify-send -t 1000 Recognized: " + std::to_string(predicted);
        system(notifyCmd.c_str());

    }catch(cv::Exception ex){

    }

}
```

I've ran it in terminal and it worked.

Here's an implementation of createCvMatFromRaw:

```
cv::Mat HelloWorld::createCvMatFromRaw(unsigned char *rawData, int rawXW, int rawYW, int ch)
{
    cv::Mat cvMat( rawYW, rawXW, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    for (int py=0; py<rawYW; py++) {
        for (int px=0; px<rawXW; px++) {
            int nBasePos = ((rawXW * py)+px) * ch;
            cvMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(py, px) = cv::Vec4b(rawData[nBasePos + 0],
                                                    rawData[nBasePos + 1],
                                                    rawData[nBasePos + 2],
                                                    0xFF);

        }
    }

    return cvMat;
}
```

I've found it here:

http://blog.szmake.net/archives/845

What does this assert mean? Can someone explain it to me? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion says

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F)`

which means that the sample either doesn't have the right number of columns or doesn't have type `CV_32F`.

It looks like you forgot the `reshape` function, so your data violates the first condition. I think in order to apply `svm`, the data needs to be a vector, i.e. `1 x n` matrix.

Comment: cv::Mat testMat2 = testMat.clone().reshape(1, 1); - I tried it and result is the same.

Comment: I even tried: cv::cvtColor(testMat, greyMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Comment: Ok it worked with imread! The problem is I need to use conversion from cocos2d-x data array and it'll dynamically change and saving/reading is a bad for performance.

Comment: I don't understand your `createCvMatFromRaw`. It looks like it returns a 4-channel Mat with `alpha=255`, while `ch=3` since you are working with a jpeg image. That's why `cvtColor` doesn't work, as neither `reshape`: the data size doesn't match. It should be `cvtColor(testMat, greyMat, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)`. Note that default color space for OpenCV is BGR(A) while others' (CCImage) are usually RGBA.

Comment: It worked! :) That was the missing piece. Now I should somehow optimize the code to reduce number of conversions (createCvMatFromRaw, cvtColor, reshape, convertTo).